# How to add conditional statement to mySQL update query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have the following mySQL update query. How can I add a conditional WHEN statement in that says if Status = "PS" change to "PE" and if Status = "DS" change to "DE"

I am not sure how this can be written with the correct syntax.

```
 UPDATE Equipment SET delivery_time = "5 pm",
 stop_sequence = "Stop 2" 
WHERE (status = "Fixed" or status = "Broken")
 AND customer = "Mary" AND driver = "Pete"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use case when

```
 UPDATE Equipment SET delivery_time = '5 pm',
 stop_sequence = 'Stop 2',
 status = case  status when 'PS' then 'PE' when 'DS' Then 'DE'
          else status end
 WHERE status in ('Fixed' 'Broken')
 AND customer = 'Mary' AND driver = 'Pete'
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct, the question is: How can I update PS to PE and DS to DE if the criteria is met

Comment: I still need my original WHERE statement

Comment: It is only doing `when status='PS' then 'PE'` it not doing `when 'DS' Then 'DE'`

Comment: @RelsonJames i little bit edited could you check one more time

Comment: It seems to work but stop_sequence is not being updated

Comment: Have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

use if statement

UPDATE Equipment SET delivery_time = '5 pm', stop_sequence = 'Stop 2',
status = IF(status='PS', 'PE', IF(status='DS', 'DE', 'NULL') 
WHERE status in ('PS' 'DS')
 AND customer = 'Mary' AND driver = 'Pete'